# Can't launch struts2-archetype-starter:2.3.7

Tags: struts2, maven-3

This is the error I get after selecting the archetype from the list generated:

[image: error image]

I've read the content of the site it displayed but that doesn't help. Are the archetypes listed here out of date or something? Based on this error would I have to create a new archetype using Eclipse to get at the struts2-archetype-starter?

Thanks

P.S. Thanks all for patience in my quest to understand and get Struts 2 working!

Comment: Please post text, not images of text. Can't even read it all anyway. Can't you just start with the Struts 2 blank webapp that comes with the distro?

Comment: yeh i went for that - too much headache getting the starter working for some reason - Cheers all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working fine you haven't mentioned when you are getting the problem(which goal you were trying to execute).

```
313: remote -> org.apache.struts:struts2-archetype-blank (-)
314: remote -> org.apache.struts:struts2-archetype-convention
315: remote -> org.apache.struts:struts2-archetype-dbportlet (
316: remote -> org.apache.struts:struts2-archetype-plugin (-)
317: remote -> org.apache.struts:struts2-archetype-portlet (-)
318: remote -> org.apache.struts:struts2-archetype-starter (-)
```

Choose 313 instead of 318.